# Cannot bind automatically in AJAX post request to a Java object in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I have two issues:

1. Cannot get my parameters automatically bound into an Java object (they are being
   posted with jQuery using AJAX)
2. I am getting a 406 error, I think this means I am not being able to return the JSON object I would like to

I believe the two problem are different, but the solution to both rely in the same part of the code. Could you help me please? Thanks a lot in advance!

**Ajax Request**

I am trying to post a very simple object, having an email and a name, like this.

```
var dataObject = {
    name : this.userName,
    email : this.userEmail,
};
this.$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : '/stock-events/register-to-stock',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data : JSON.stringify(dataObject),
    success : function(data) {
        console.info("data");
    },
    dataType : 'json'
});
```

**Spring MCV Controller**

```
    @ResponseBody @RequestMapping(value = "/register-to-stock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public StockAlarmJsonResponse submitForm(@Valid @RequestBody StockAlarmModel stockAlarm,
        BindingResult result, Model m) {
    System.out.println("hola");
    System.out.println(stockAlarm);
    StockAlarmJsonResponse response = new StockAlarmJsonResponse();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(result);
        response.fail();
    }else{
        System.out.println(stockAlarm);
        response.success();
    }
    return response;
}
```

**Model**

```
  public class StockAlarmModel {


@NotNull @Max(100) @Email
private String email;

@Max(100)
private String name;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Email: " + email + '\n' + "Name: " + name;
}
}
```

**Error I get in Java (looks like the parameters are not there)**

```
 org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
 Field error in object 'stockAlarmModel' on field 'email': rejected value [null]; codes   [NotNull.stockAlarmModel.email,NotNull.email,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [stockAlarmModel.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email]]; default message [may not be null]
```

**Error I get in chrome bug (looks that json object is not being returned successfully)**

```
  POST http://localhost:8080/stock-events/register-to-stock 400 (Bad Request) jquery-     1.9.1.js:8526
  send jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
  jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.1.js:7978
  StockAlarm.registerAlarm StockAlarm.js:131
  (anonymous function) StockAlarm.js:87
 jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle
```

**What Chrome Bug Shows for Request**

Content Type / Application Json

Request Payload:

```
{"name":"santiago","email":"santiago@tiendanube.com"}
```

Comment: With firebug, show us the actual request body being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that jQuery will serialize this

```
var dataObject = {
    name : this.userName,
    email : this.userEmail,
};
```

into json such as

```
{"name" : "some username", "email" : "some email"}
```

You'll therefore want Spring to bind a JSON object to your command object. Change your method to

```
public @ResponseBody StockAlarmJsonResponse submitForm(@Valid @RequestBody StockAlarmModel stockAlarm, BindingResult result, Model m) {
```

Note the [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) (which can be used with `@Valid`). Spring will use an `HttpMessageConverter` to attempt to deserialize the JSON into an instance of your `StockAlarmModel`. I'm not sure if the object will be added to the `Model` directly. You can always add it yourself if you need to.

AFAIK [`ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) tries to bind request parameters to the command object. You don't have request parameters in your ajax request.

Comment: I think you have pointed me in the right direction, however, i still cannot make it work. I have changed the way the request is being done, I have specified it to send content type json, and I have alson converted the object itself to json (see edit above).
Now, the problem is that I don't even get to the controller, meaning that I wont be able to do a println.

Comment: @user Set your logger to trace/debug and check for any messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your object is being created correctly.

As posted earlier, @RequestBody will attempt to deserialize the JSON object to to the annotated type but you need to have **setters** in your entity's class. Try adding this to your model:

```
public class StockAlarmModel {
  .
  .
  .
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email= email;
  }
}
```